# How can I prepare user command on the next bash prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash

Let's say the command I'm looking for, is `prepare`

If I launch:

```
$ prepare git commit
```

Then it will just insert `git commit` into my next prompt (but doesn't execute it):

```
$ prepare git commit
$ git commit # <-- I didn't write this, the prepare command did it
```

I'm looking for possible implementation of the `prepare` command.

**Is it possible with pure `bash` or there will be needed any third party program?**

Can you provide an example?

Comment: What would be the actual use case for this?

Comment: How does this save you any time? I'd be looking to create a function, but your requirements are too vague.

Comment: @glennjackman it's not always only about saving time, but many times also about the user experience

Comment: @Seth I can see many use cases, the only limit is our imagination:

1. `prepare $(history | grep that_awesome_command)`
2. a script could optionally prepare the same command it was executed with (e.g. when showing help of a script - that could speed up things)

Comment: I don't get what your first example is supposed to do. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000410/using-bash-history-to-get-a-previous-command-copy-it-and-then-run-it-but-with) would suggest using history would be sufficient - if it's supposed to just grab that command and prepare it for execution. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1130688/bash-how-to-output-command-to-next-prompt-for-user-to-use) seems to discuss what you want to do.

Comment: @Seth this is exactly why I didn't want to provide any example to you - you try to find another solution

Comment: I know about Ctrl + r to interact with history
I didn't know about `xdotool`, thanks for that :) .. but anyways, is this possible to implement using pure bash ? Consider this question as a tool to improve my bash skills

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you would have to look at how bash interacts with its devices. You might be able to write to one of those to make it display what you want. Additionally, assuming you want to run that prepare from within a script, you would have to take the invocation into account as the script might start its own bash. The likely answer is no as it could (easily) be used for mischievous things and what would stop you from "preparing" that `\n` in order to get it executed right away? In addition its pretty easy to output a command and let the user copy paste it if he wants to run it.